# makefile: execute one target from another target plus additional commands

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with something like the following targets:

```
install:
    do a whole bunch of stuff to install

dist: install
    cp README.txt $(INSTALL_DIR)
    zip $(INSTALL_DIR)
```

I am trying to not repeat the commands from target `install` and make `dist` execute `install` first before executing its own commands.

Calling `make dist` does indeed execute all commands from target `install` but then just stops and it does not execute its own commands, e.g. the `cp`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Normally, your 'install' rule would depend on 'all' or thereabouts, and 'all' would do the 'whole bunch of stuff to build', leaving 'install' to do the 'whole bunch of stuff to install'.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, that's actually what it is doing. I will edit that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to add this line in your makefile

.PHONY : install dist

Comment: That was it. Can you elaborate why this is necessary? Thanks.

Comment: Was the install directory called 'install' (or perhaps 'dist')?  That tends to confuse things.  The '.PHONY' notation (a GNU Make extension) means roughly that the 'target' is to be treated as always out of date.

Comment: To elaborate on what Jonathan said about .PHONY, think of it like this: Make assumes all targets are actual files and looks to see if it can find the file, if it can't the file is considered out of date and the rule executed. .PHONY tells make that it's not really a file, so don't look for it or try to match it to any patterns/rules and of course if there really is a file/directory called that, don't take that file to be the target, potentially treating the target as up to date. http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Phony-Targets.html